# Spark reuse broadcast DF

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to reuse my DataFrame (without falling back to doing this using "Map" function in RDD/Dataset) which I marking as broadcast-eable, but seems Spark keeps broadcasting it again and again.

Having a table "bank" (test table). I perform the following:

```
  val cachedDf = spark.sql("select * from bank").cache
  cachedDf.count

  val dfBroadcasted = broadcast(cachedDf)

  val dfNormal = spark.sql("select * from bank")

  dfNormal.join(dfBroadcasted, List("age"))
    .join(dfBroadcasted, List("age")).count
```

I'm caching before just in case it made a difference, but its the same with or without.

If I execute the above code, I see the following SQL plan:

[image: SQL plan for the code]

As you can see, my broadcasted DF gets broadcasted TWICE with also different timings (if I add more actions afterwards, they broadcast again too).

I care about this, because I actually have a long-running program which has a "big" DataFrame which I can use to filter out HUGE DataFrames, and I would like that "big" DataFrame to be reused.

Is there a way to force reusability? (not only inside the same action, but between actions, I could survive with the same action tho)

Thanks!,

Comment: how about caching dfBroadcasted too?

Comment: @mangusta tried that, didn't work either, doesn't matter if I cache before or after. Also tried spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold -1

Comment: Are you sure it gets broadcasted twice? Just because the SQL plan visualiser is just a simple high-level translation of the Optimised plan and it tends to hide some parts. The way I understand it, it worked as it is written in your code, the table was cached and the InMemoryTable scan (i.e. the cached one) was used for each join, which can be worked on in parallel... but I'd suggest letting Spark optimiser to decide when broadcasting is necessary for you, since it is not a good idea to broadcast a huge table to each node and fill up all the executor memory instantly.

Comment: Hi Richard, that's why I was pointing the timing thing, both visualisers show different timings, so I would bet its being done twice (otherwise it should have the same timing).

Spark optimiser doesn't know the size of that table as it doesn't come from Hive (its generated in the middle of the execution).  My real table is upto 6million registries (its just two small strings per row), but it can be used to filter tables of 6.000 million registries with many columns before any shuffling is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, updating the question.

**Summarising:** 
INSIDE the same action, left_semis will reuse broadcasts
while normal/left joins won't. Not sure related with the fact that Spark/developers already know the columns of that DF won't affect the output at all so they can reuse it or it's just an optimization spark is missing.

My problem seems mostly-solved, **although it would be great if someone knew how to keep the broadcast across actions.**

If I use left_semi (which is the join i'm going to use in my real app), the broadcast is only performed once.

With:

```
    dfNormalxx.join(dfBroadcasted, Seq("age"),"left_semi")
.join(dfBroadcasted, Seq("age"),"left_semi").count
```

The plan becomes (I also changed the size so it matches my real one, but this made no difference):

[image]

Also the wall total time is much better than when using "left_semi" (I set 1 executor so it doesn't get parallelized, just wanted to check if the job was really being done twice):

[image]

Even though my collect takes 10 seconds, this will speedup table reads+groupBys which are taking like 6-7minutes

Comment: So the general statement across actions i snot correct, it's a specific case. Interesting.